# A PDF file on my Desktop shows up with the name and properties of my root drive

Tags: finder, macos, pdf

I am using a 2009 13" MacBook Pro running El Capitan 10.11. On my desktop, I strangely have a PDF with the name "Macintosh HD" and the properties of my main system drive.

[image: The Properties window of the PDF file]

Does anybody know why this is happening, or how I can resolve it?

Comment: The creation date is 23 December '17. Has it been there since that date, or did it just appear on the desktop.

Comment: @IconDaemon It's been on the desktop since then, if memory serves.

Comment: BURN IT WITH FIRE! – But seriously though, you should report the file to an antivirus firm and *don't open it*. Google "report virus file for analysis". There will be links to trendmicro, microsoft, symantec, etc. Any of those should be fine.

Comment: If you are curious what the contents are (and you know how to use the Terminal), you can try the following commands. **Get actual file size:** `ls -lh ~/Desktop/Macintosh\ HD*`. **Print the last 1000 bytes of the file:** `tail -c -1000 "enter the full name from the above command here" ; echo ""` (Change the 1000 as needed. Keep the `; echo ""` part because it's needed in case the file does not end in a new line.)

Comment: Correction to my "burn it with fire" comment: Since it's a mac, the companies I mentioned above might not find anything wrong with the file, so you can google "report virus file for analysis sophos" instead. Sophos makes antivirus software for macs. But even if none of these find the file as malicious, you should still be careful. Use my `tail` command from above to view the contents safely.

Comment: @Vladimir Apparently, the file "Macintosh HD" doesn't exist on the Desktop when running the file size command, and running an `ls` in the directory pulls back nothing either. Odd.

Comment: Let me bet on "annoying bug, but harmless": what are its properties in Terminal? (`ls -ashilo` on the file, [with GNU ls, with `/bin/ls` add e]) and `less`? Also try to toggle all Finder preferences under General to not show anything on Desktop, then restart Finder.

Comment: The file apparently couldn't be found, @LangLangC. Toggled and it appears to have disappeared — thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all likelihood this is a bug.

A "real" PDF, or a malicious file (which would probably better hidden or disguised), would not show for "Get Info" things like "Capacity" etc.

If under Finder > Preferences > General the checkbox is set to
"Show these items on the desktop:  harddisks" it just is displaying the correct name for the internal drive: "Macintosh HD" but mixes up somehow the filetype/association.

That means the suspected explanation in the question is exactly backwards:
Somehow the root drive/volume "Macintosh HD" is reported as kind "PDF".

To confirm this scenario, open a Terminal, type `file` (note the trailing space!) and drag the offending icon onto the Terminal window.

You should now see the following output or something similar:

```
$ file / 
/: directory
```

If that is the case, the solution is quite simple:

Open again the Finder preferences in the general tab and uncheck the "show hard disks on desktop" option,

[image]

and restart the Finder with a method of your choice. That might include a logout, login cycle, or just type in Terminal:

```
$ killall Finder
```

Now, even if you you re-tick that checkbox, your hard disk should show up with the proper icon and filetype.

If these steps fail, deleting the Finder preferences, and then the caches might be the next steps.